# Windows 8.1 computer repeatedly wakes up and goes to sleep again

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, sleep

I put my computer (Windows 8.1 Pro) to sleep every evening.

**For a couple days now, I find it awake in the morning.** A quick check in Event Viewer shows that it actually woke up and (apparently) put itself back to sleep again many times during the night, about every half hour.

[image: Event Viewer this morning]

**This is new and was not happening three days ago.** I have already taken great care to make sure my computer doesn't wake up for no good reason:

1. Windows Update is setup to download updates but to let me choose whether or when to install them:

[image: Windows Update Settings]

2. Wake timers are disabled for the power plan I'm using:

[image: Power Options]

3. I prevented all devices from waking the computer up:

   ```
   C:\>powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
   NONE
   ```
4. As far as I can tell, no active Scheduled Task is allowed to wake the computer up to run.
5. A quick check with Windows Defender (with up-to-date definitions) does not detect any malware (not that Windows Defender is really good at finding them...)

A few more (possibly unrelated) details:

- My computer has been up for 10 days now. This isn't unusual, I often reach uptimes of 30 days or more.
- I often have (paused) YouTube videos open in browser tabs when I put the computer to sleep. Again this hasn't caused problems so far.

**Any idea what could be causing this, and how to make sure my computer does not wake up?**

Comment: Observed in Windows 7 as well, guess it's due to some patch Microsoft installed that breaks hibernation mode. No surprise, they break stuff many times. :/

Comment: That's very possible. Interestingly, sleep mode has been working again for a few days.

Comment: Not for me. Hopefully this will either resolve itself (new patch?) or we'll get answer here. :)